# Is there a algorithm to resolve credit rating?

Tags: java, sql, arrays, plsql

I need to implement a logic in either Java OR SQL for the following.

There are credit ratings from numbers 1 to 11.
And corresponding to each rating say x, I have 3 grades, effectively :x+, x and x-.
Difference between each grade is termed as a step. For example, 2 and 2- is single(1) step,2+ and 2- is double(2) step, and 2- and 3+ is again a single(1) step.

My objective is to programmatically find out the number of steps between two credit rating values, until the difference in number of steps is 3.

I tried to solve this problem using conditional (if-else/case) statements, but a deeper analysis led to the conclusion that this would require about 50 odd such statements, which is not a very efficient thing to do, at least in terms of code layout.

Is there any other way to get the number of steps? Perhaps using a temporary data structure, and then using that for lookup?

Note: I can have the two credit rating values pulled into Java Code from DB and then compute number of steps.
Alternatively, I need to create a database object(like procedure, function) and then have the number of steps computed that way, such that my Java code can directly consume it.

Comment: Looks like given a rating `N`, `N` is `N*3 - 1`, `N-` is `N*3 -2` and `N+` is `N*3`. From there calculating the steps between two ratings is trivial.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca,I think that approach doesn't work always, example 7- and 8.Using the above method gives me (7*3)-2=19 and (8*3)-1=23.The difference between these two values are 4.Whereas the number of steps between them is just 2(7-,8+,8)

Comment: Oops, I thought the order was `N-<N<N+`. If you move the calculations around to have them in the order you want it should work.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ,below is sample data: Credit rating 1 and 2 are my inputs, steps is what will be my output. In explanation field, each '=>' indicates a step.   https://imgur.com/a/JP72Vdz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just assign a numeric value to each rating and have a function that subtracts one from the other.

```
create or replace package rating
as
    function diff(r1 varchar2, r2 varchar2)
        return integer
        deterministic
        parallel_enable;
end rating;
/
```

```
create or replace package body rating
as
    type rating_tab is table of simple_integer index by varchar2(3);
    ratings rating_tab;

    function diff(r1 varchar2, r2 varchar2)
        return integer
        deterministic
        parallel_enable
    is
        pragma udf;
    begin
        return ratings(r2) - ratings(r1);
    end diff;

begin
    ratings('1+')  := 1;
    ratings('1+')  := 2;
    ratings('1')   := 3;
    ratings('1-')  := 4;
    ratings('2+')  := 5;
    ratings('2')   := 6;
    ratings('2-')  := 7;
    ratings('3+')  := 8;
    ratings('3')   := 9;
    ratings('3-')  := 10;
    ratings('4+')  := 11;
    ratings('4')   := 12;
    ratings('4-')  := 14;
    ratings('5+')  := 15;
    ratings('5')   := 16;
    ratings('5-')  := 17;
    ratings('6+')  := 18;
    ratings('6')   := 19;
    ratings('6-')  := 20;
    ratings('7+')  := 21;
    ratings('7')   := 22;
    ratings('7-')  := 23;
    ratings('8+')  := 24;
    ratings('8')   := 25;
    ratings('8-')  := 26;
    ratings('9+')  := 27;
    ratings('9')   := 28;
    ratings('9-')  := 29;
    ratings('10+') := 30;
    ratings('10')  := 31;
    ratings('10-') := 32;
    ratings('11+') := 33;
    ratings('11')  := 34;
    ratings('11-') := 35;
end rating;
/
```

```
select rating.diff('1-', '3+') as steps from dual;

    STEPS
---------
        4
```

I am not sure whether a PL/SQL function is acceptable though, since you started by saying you wanted to use either Java or SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to define a table that has all the credit ratings with their position:

```
create table creditratings as
    select 1 as ord, 1 as number, '-' as grade from dual union all
    select 2 as ord, 1 as number, ' ' as grade from dual union all
    select 3 as ord, 1 as number, '+' as grade from dual union all
    . . .
```

Then for any credit rating, you can use `lead()` or `lag()` to get the next or previous one -- or one 3 steps away.

As you have described the problem, though, `number - 1` or `number + 1` gets the rating three steps away.